# Algorithm for my project in android

Tags: java, android

I have a android project that generates random numbers as the button's text. If you click a button the value of the corresponding button should be displayed in the edittext.

I am already getting the value of the buttons and also able to display it in the edittext. I have 12 buttons and 2 edittexts. What I want is, if I will do the first click then first value will display in the first edittext and in the second click the value will display in the second edittext.

My problem is that in the first click the value is getting displayed in the 2 edittexts simultaneously. Hope you can help me, here is my code:

```
b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first);
    et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.second);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            str=((Button)v).getText().toString();
            et1.setText(str);
            et2.setText(str);
        }
    });
```

- `b1` = one of the buttons.
- `et1` and `et2`= the two edittexts.
- str = empty string

Comment: Check if et1 is empty and if it is, then set text in et1. Else, set text in et2.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't surprise me. You don't distinguish your cases within your onClickListener.

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            str=((Button)v).getText().toString();
            // Check which edit text
            if(isFirstClick()) {
               et1.setText(str);
               setFirstClick(false);
            } else {
               et2.setText(str);
            }
        }
    });
```

See the 'isFirstClick()' like some kind of pseudo code, maybe you can also check if your first editbox is still empty or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Both @Averroes and @Sambuca have provided a smiliar solution which should work:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        str=((Button)v).getText().toString();
        if((et1.getText().toString()).equals(""))
          et1.setText(str);
        else
          et2.setText(str);
    }
});
```

In case you can do more than 2 clicks and your requirement is to output to textBox1 on odd clisk and Textbox2 on even click - use a boolean variable.